# How to translate the date and the number from English to Arabic in asp:BoundField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

*This is my HTML. I want the date in the DataGridView to be in arabic and i want the solution in details because am beginner in asp.net*

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" CellPadding="3" 
 AllowSorting="True" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                         DataKeyNames="id" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="stat_date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="التاريخ" ItemStyle-Font Size="Small"/>
```

*I found this code but i don't know where to put it or even how to use it with grid view*

```
   public string ConvertIntoLocalNumerals(string EnglishValue, string Locale)
   {
       string[] numerals = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Locale).NumberFormat.Nati     veDigits;

        string LocalisedValue = EnglishValue;
        for(int n=0; n < numerals.Length; n++)
        {
            LocalisedValue = LocalisedValue.Replace(n.ToString(), numerals[n]);
        }
        return LocalisedValue;
    }
```

Comment: IN ENGLISH, ALL CAPITOL LETTERS LOOKS LIKE YOU ARE SHOUTING. Please don't do that.

Comment: Please don't shout - and put more effort into formatting your code. It's a complete mess at the moment.

Comment: You can put that code many places like before assiging the data source to grid format the field or in rowbound format that value .

Comment: I put it in aspx but It return error  UTF8Encoding() could not be found but when I tried to put it in html before boundfield in htm lit gave me lot of errors public string ConvertIntoLocalNumerals(string EnglishValue, string Locale)
   {
       string[] numerals = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Locale).NumberFormat.Nati     veDigits;

        string LocalisedValue = EnglishValue;
        for(int n=0; n < numerals.Length; n++)
        {
            LocalisedValue = LocalisedValue.Replace(n.ToString(), numerals[n]);
        }
        return LocalisedValue;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. One is you can create a template field instead of Bound field and other is you can do it on rowDataBound Method.

Here is the code for template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="التاريخ">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#ConvertIntoLocalNumerals(Eval("stat_date").ToString(),"ar-sa") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Following is the code to do it in RowDataBound Method

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var arabicDate = ConvertIntoLocalNumerals(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "start_date").ToString(),"ar-sa");
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", arabicDate);
    }
}
```

***Update***

You can localized the DateTime Object instead of string and here is helper method.

```
public string ConvertIntoLocaleDate(DateTime SourceValue, string Locale,string format)
{
    var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Locale);
    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    string formattedDate = SourceValue.ToString(format, cultureInfo);
    string[] numerals = cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NativeDigits;

    for (int n = 0; n < numerals.Length; n++)
    {
        formattedDate = formattedDate.Replace(n.ToString(), numerals[n]);
    }
    return formattedDate;
}
```

and your rowDataBound code will be as follows

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ConvertIntoLocaleDate(Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "start_date")), "ar-sa", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: thank you but It return( ٢/٤/٢٠١٥ ١٢:٠٠:٠٠ AM ) how to ٢٠١٥/٢/٤   in this formate

Comment: i used the row data bound you gave it to me but it gives me same format ( ٢/٤/٢٠١٥ ١٢:٠٠:٠٠ AM )

Comment: That's becasue your helper method `ConvertIntoLocalNumerals` is returning string, instead of date.

Comment: thank you but do you have idea how to make it appear from right to left ??

Comment: instead of that ٢/٤/٢٠١٥ I need it to be like that ٢٠١٥/٢/٤

Comment: Yes, that's pretty easy, you just need to pass the format as yyyy/MM/dd in your rowDataBound

Comment: thank you but one more question if I want to apply the code that translate English number to Arabic  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit">
     <ItemTemplate>
               
                    <asp:Label ID="credit" runat="server"  Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
                    
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: If you need to change a lot of things to Arabic, consider changing the culture of your page/application to Arabic. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.140).aspx